# Order query by number of times one model has another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following structure:

`User`  model: id, ..
`Event` model: id, ..
`UserMapEvent` model: user_id, event_id

For example the `UserMapEvent` table might have the following records:

```
User_id | Event_id
   1    |     1
   1    |     2
   3    |     1
   4    |     1
```

I'm using this structure to save when a user likes an event.

Now, if I'm in the shows controller and I know the event's id, I can get the number of times the user liked the event like:

```
`likes = UsersMapEvent.where("event_id = ?", event.id).count`
```

How do I get, for example, the top 3 liked events? Do I have to join the 2 tables?

The only solution that  I could think of is to use `Event.all` and for each to do the exact same thing, but it sounds stupid and I assume this is not one of those cases 'if it's stupid and it works is fine'.

What type of database operation do I have to use to get my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may select top 3 liked events with next code:

```
Event.left_joins(:users_map_events).group(:id).order('COUNT(users_map_events.id) DESC').limit(3)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. Can you point to something to read so I can understand what's going on in there?

Comment: You may read about `ActiveRecord` query methods in Rails documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html. Also your connection scheme between `User` and `Event` same as Rails `has_many :through` association. So you may read related documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.